# How to call a C function from assembly

Tags: c, assembly

I am programming x86 assembly in Visual Studio 2012.

I'm trying to call printf from an assembly program, but it throws an error as soon as I include the EXTERN line. It's probably something really stupid like including the library of C functions but I can't find any online resource that tells me how to do it right.

Here's my code:

```
.model flat

            EXTERN  _printf

.data

digits      byte    "0" dup (10), 0         

.code

main proc

            lea     eax,    digits
            push    eax
            call    _printf
            add     esp,    4

main endp

END
```

And the error thrown is:

```
error A2008: syntax error : in directive
```

on line 3 (the line with EXTERN)

EDIT: Added information about environment (the first line).

Comment: It is compiler and assembler specific, but that said, the only thing that looks foreign is `EXTERN` instead of `extern` and some assemblers are picky about `printf` instead of `_printf` but most handle both. How are you compiling? Assemble, link with `ld` (manually) or calling `gcc` for both?

Comment: I already tried all of those. I'm using Visual Studio 2012. I'm not sure how it's assembling it, but it's an x86 console application.

Comment: [`EXTERN _printf:proc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7cycf5bc.aspx)

Comment: See the manual page for the [EXTERN directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7cycf5bc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). `EXTERN [[langtype]] name [[(altid)]] :
   type [[, [[langtype]] name [[(altid)]] :type]]...`. `type` is not optional.

Comment: Adding ":proc" seems to help but it is still throwing an error. This time it says "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _printf referenced in function main." I tried without the underscore and it gave the same error (except without the underscore in the error message).

Comment: @DroidFreak36 Then you're already one step further. That error means that you have to link to the standard library, where `printf` resides.

Comment: Have you tried linking to MSVCRT.lib ?

Comment: "That error means that you have to link to the standard library, where printf resides."

So how do I do that?

Comment: @DroidFreak36 - you probably need to do an includelib. I added an answer showing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, use

```
        extern  _printf:proc
```

or if 32 bit mode, you may need to use:

```
        extern  _printf:near
```

externs may need to be placed in the .code section.

Also add these two lines near the top of your source code to cause the linker to look in these libraries.

```
        includelib   msvcrtd
        includelib   oldnames
```

Comment: Using `EXTERN _printf:proc` with those includelib lines fixed it, thanks.

Comment: @DroidFreak36 - if you want to call windows functions, like CreateFile(), create a C program and have the compiler output assembly code to determing the assembly names. Even though it's C, the function names are some what [mangled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling), such as __imp__CreateFileA@28 (32 bit mode) or __imp_CreateFile (64 bit mode).